# Method returning null value to database statement

Tags: java, sql

I have a method as follows in a class named ProductInsert:

```
public float insertPrice() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter Product Price:");
            setProductPrice(scanFloat.nextFloat());
        }catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            new ProductInsert().insertPrice();
        }
        return getProductPrice();
    }
```

I have another class named ProductServices, with the following Prepared statement database execution:

```
            PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            pstm.setFloat(2, insertPrice());
```

So when the user inputs a string value "asdfad" when asked for price, it return an InputMismatch Exception and calls the insertPrice method again. And in the case when it is called the second time, and the user enters a float value "230.00" the pstm.setfloat gets a null value and inserts "0.00" in the database instead of "230.00". WHY???

setter and getter for product price:

```
public float getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(float productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }
```

Comment: Show `setProductPrice()` and `getProductPrice()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is an exception, you create a **new** instance `new ProductInsert().insertPrice();`.

The returned value from the initial call to `insertPrice()` is the value from this `ProductPrice` instance (the one where you prepare the statement), which is not set (or set to 0.0).

In the `catch`, call directly `insertPrice()` without `new ProductPrice()`, but you certainly need to *reset* or consume the wrong input, e.g.

```
 //...
 catch (InputMismatchException e){
      System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
      scanFloat.nextLine(); // will "eat" the wrong entry
      insertPrice(); // try again
 }
```

Comment: when i call insertPrice() directly, it goes into an infinite loop. any more suggestions?

Comment: Because `scanFloat()` does not consume the input when it is not a float. Is `scanFloat` a `Scanner` instance?

Comment: yep scanFloat() is a scanner instance

Comment: `nextLine()` instead of `readLine()`... as corrected by @realskeptic. What's wrong now? always in infinite loop?